# Mysql slow copying to tmp table to indexing

Tags: mysql, index, mariadb, myisam

I try to indexing table.
The table size is about 60GB.
But indexing query is hang on 'copying to tmp table' 18 hours.
I found advice setting 'myisam_sort_buffer_size'

myisam_sort_buffer_size : 128M
RAM : 32GB
Window Server, MariaDB

Is it Okay increase to myisam_sort_buffer_size setting value?
Could you recommened myisam_sort_buffer_size value?

What can I do to speed up add index?

Comment: DBAs would be in a lot better position to answer this question than sw developers.

Comment: If you remove the index before inserting and then add it again after the inserting has complete, you could see a performance boost.

Comment: MySQL 5.6 can add an index with zero downtime in many cases.  But you need to be running InnoDB.

Comment: Does it say "repair by keycache" or "repair by sorting"?  (Look at `SHOW PROCESSLIST`.)

Comment: How big is the index?  What are the values of `key_buffer_size` and `myisam_max_sort_file_size`?

Comment: @Rick James  Looking at PROCESSLIST state is 'copying to tmp table' , I think before step 'repair by sorting'. key_buffer_size is 128MB, myisam_max_sort_file_size is 2GB.

Comment: If yours is MariaDB 10 then you should use `alter ONLINE table` ... for speed yes you can try tuning buffers... https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/alter-table/  with copy

Comment: I think `repair by sorting` is faster.  But keep in mind that 60GB is a lot to shovel around.

Comment: You can try with: https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-online-schema-change.html